# javascript "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textfield' of undefined"

Tags: javascript

```
    for(i=0; i<=entryArray.length; i++) {
        $(colorChange[entryArray[i]]['textfield']).ColorPicker({
            color: "FFFFFF",
            onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                $(colorChange[entryArray[i]]['textfield']).val("#" + hex);
                $(colorChange[entryArray[i]]['className']).css(colorChange[entryArray[i]]['cssEntry'], "#" + hex);
            }
        })
    }
```

I got this error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textfield' of undefined`

Comment: you link is not working

Comment: Can you add your html code?

Comment: @ozil, pastebin banned in Russia.

Comment: Don't use `new Array`. Better use `[]`.

Comment: i´ve add a "snippet" of the code. @sigod thanks, i´ve changed this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in combination of `for` loop and function definition.

```
$(colorChange[entryArray[i]]['textfield']).val("#" + hex);
```

`onChange` function captures reference to `i` variable. Not the value itself.

Code can be fixed like this:

```
entryArray.forEach(function (entry) {
        $(colorChange[entry]['textfield']).ColorPicker({
                color: "FFFFFF",
                onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                        $(colorChange[entry]['textfield']).val("#" + hex);
                        $(colorChange[entry]['className']).css(colorChange[entry]['cssEntry'], "#" + hex);
                }
        });
});
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/944911) for more details.

---

I also should mention problems with `for` loop itself.

```
for (i = 0; i <= entryArray.length; i++)
```

- `<=` incorrect in this case. You eventually end up with `i === entryArray.length`, while last element in the array has index `entryArray.length - 1`. Use `<`.
- `i` escapes from current scope and goes directly to the global (always use `var i = 0;`, unless you want to reuse some local variable)